# how to stop banner from displaying immediately after linux log in

Tags: linux, unix

I'm using a virtual machine from a Provider. As soon as i log in to that machine they display their policy as a banner. How could I remove that?

Comment: This is better suited to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/motd` using any text editor.